# Creating points along lines using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a point along a line given distance](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11992/how-to-create-a-point-along-a-line-given-distance)
>   [How to create equidistant points in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27102/how-to-create-equidistant-points-in-qgis)

I have some road survey data and each line has an individual value and defect data (which is given as a figure in meters of how far down that line it is) and I was wondering if it would be possible to generate points at the chainages given for these defects in relation to the lines they are on using the direction the line has been drawn in.

Comment: have you seen this  http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/45351/how-can-i-represent-distance-using-the-dashes-or-markers-of-a-vector-line/45371#45371

Comment: Yeah, the plugin doesn't work in my version of QGIS (1.8)

"The only thing is that the plugin is currently working in master only"

Is this a newer (unstable version) of QGIS?

Comment: QGIS 1.9.0 Master is a development release but it is not unstable (at least not in my experience).  It also has a lot of improvements over Lisboa and I highly commend it to you - especially if you need this plugin.

Comment: The question I have linked to as duplicate has a method that uses the Python shapely module if you are stuck on 1.8.