# LRS plugin does not return measure field.

Tags: qgis, linear-referencing

Does anyone know how to use the LRS plugin in QGIS 2.18.14?

I have a layer of roads and points I need to determine the distance along the roads. I tried but I can not get a measure field.

Does anyone know the step by step what needs to be processed first and what fields should layers contain?

[image]

Comment: Haven't really used it much but you could take a look at the [documentation](http://blazek.github.io/lrs/release/help.0.3.7/index.html) :)

Comment: I've been looking there but unsuccessful. I get empty fields. Maybe plugin is broken. here is similar answer https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/219082/qgis-plugin-that-adds-a-point-along-a-line-at-a-specified-distance?rq=1 but the same result

Comment: Can you provide test data?

Comment: test data: http://www.mediafire.com/file/22mmk9uqc8r80zl/LRS_data.rar. I tried with QGIS weekly, nothing again...